# Correct way to update sate object field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, use-state

I am trying to add an array to a field of a state object the correct way and I cannot seem to figure it out.

I have two separate functional components.

Component A makes the beginning of the object:

```js
const beginning = {
    FormId: 0,
    Company: "",
    CreatedBy: "",
    CreatedWhen: "",
    LastModified: "",
    LastModifiedBy: "",
    Payload: []
}
```

Component B makes the value for the `Payload` field (an array of objects). So the final object looks like this:

```js
const finishedJSON = {
    FormId: 0,
    Company: "",
    CreatedBy: "",
    CreatedWhen: "",
    LastModified: "",
    LastModifiedBy: "",
    Payload: [
        {
            item: 1
        },
        {
            item: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

The object from component A is passed to component B as a prop called `metaData`

In component B, I am trying to add an array of objects to the `Payload` Field of the object.

So far, I tried this and it didn't work:

```js
export default function ComponentB({metaData}) {

    ...

    const [finishedJSON, setFinishedJSON] = useState(metaData);

    ...

    setFinishedJSON({
      ...finishedJSON,
      Payload: PayloadDataFromComponentB
    })
})

    ...
}
```

I've tried using this and it worked:

```js
export default function ComponentB({metaData}) {

    ...

    const [finishedJSON, setFinishedJSON] = useState(metaData);

    ...

    setFinishedJSON( data => {
        data.Payload = PayloadDataFromComponentB;
    })

    ...
}
```

However, I read [here](https://dev.to/horusgoul/use-react-s-usestate-and-usereducer-without-worrying-about-immutability-2a9k) that this is bad practice in React.

I also tried the `useImmer` solution from the article and unfortunately it did not update the object with the new `Payload` data

Is there a better way to update the `Payload` field? I only want to use the best practices. Let me know if im unclear. Thanks!

Comment: what is the structure of `PayloadDataFromComponentB`. Is it an array of objects?

Comment: @decpk `PayloadDataFromComponentB` is an array of objects. You can see the `Payload` field from the second code block for an example

Comment: It kind of makes little sense to pass the data from component A to component B, store it in a new state and the modify that state. By doing this you only modify the state in component B, while the data from component A remains the same. Store your data in a state in component A, then pass the state update function to component B. Call that function in component B to update the data in component A.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I think I understand what your saying. So are you saying that instead of passing the data to component A, I should pass the function that adds the modifies the data? Which would keep the state in component A

Comment: Yes, that's it. Then component B modifies the state in component A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a brand new object that has all properties. It doesn't mutate. It just returns a brand new object.

```
setFinishedJSON((data) => {
  return {
    ...data,
    payload: [ ...PayloadDataFromComponentB ]
  }
});
```

Comment: this answer did not work. When I console logged `finishedJSON` after calling the `setFinishedJSON` function, it still said that the `Payload` array is empty. Is there anymore info I can give you to help?

Comment: How are you creating the payload array? Could you add your code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/). So that I can debug what is the issue here.

Comment: here is the [link to the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-sunset-ei0ic?file=/src/App.js:0-23). In the sandbox, component A is called `MetaDataMaker` and component B is called `PayloadMaker`. Please let me know if theres problems with the sandbox, ive never used one before

Comment: @ZackBeucler You forget to spread the array `Payload: [...entireFormArray]`. Everything else is perfect [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-fast-uhfp1?file=/src/PayloadMaker.js:1503-1532)

Comment: I still dont believe so. If you add `console.log(finishedJSON)` to line 50 in the `PayloadMaker.js` file, you can see that the `Payload` array is still empty, even after the `finishedJSON` state is updated with the new `setFinishedJSON` @decpk

Comment: did you have a different result than I did? @decpk

Comment: If you log in line 50, it will not have the updated value. Remember state updates are async. I do not know the whole problem, but if you want to check if the state is updated properly or not check in the next render cycle. Probably a useEffect with no dependency array just to check out what is the state value after every update.

Comment: @TusharShahi I wasn't aware of that, my bad! I was able to find a solution by using both decpk and EmielZuurbier answers. Thank you guys for the help!